# How do I make certain texts below other texts in this case ؟

Tags: html, css

I want the texts "this is product" to be below the other texts that start with "product". How can I do this?
I tried to put the strings in the <p> element, but it didn't work, and I also set the display:block property for the <span> element, but it also didn't work.
Do I put the texts in the <div> element?

the code i used :

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

div > div {
    background-color: #eee;
    width: calc(95% / 4);
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="parent">
        <div>
            <span>Product One</span>
            <span>This is Product</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>Product Two</span>
            <span>This is Product</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>Product Three</span>
            <span>This is Product</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>Product Four</span>
            <span>This is Product</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your nested divs are also `display: flex`.  Target everything with classes or with more specificity and this will be fixed.

Comment: Assuming you stick with ```display: flex``` you can add ```flex-direction: column```

Answer (score 1):

this way ?

```css
* {
  box-sizing : border-box;
  }
div.parent {
  display          : flex;
  justify-content  : space-between;
  }
div.parent>div {
  background-color : #eee;
  width            : calc(95% / 4);
  padding          : 20px;
  }
div.parent>div>span:first-of-type {
  display : inline-block;
  width   : 100%;
  color   : red
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="parent">
    <div>
      <span>Product One</span>
      <span>This is Product</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span>Product Two</span>
      <span>This is Product</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span>Product Three</span>
      <span>This is Product</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span>Product Four</span>
      <span>This is Product</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: it should be enough to just change the first rule with div.parent and nothing else

Comment: @Lety if the line is too long (or too short), the second span will start after the previous one ...

Comment: yes, you are right. I could be possible to change span with a block element.

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.parent > div {
    background-color: #eee;
    width: calc(95% / 4);
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="parent">
        <div>
            <span>Product One</span>
            <div>This is Product</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>Product Two</span>
            <div>This is Product</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>Product Three</span>
            <div>This is Product</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>Product Four</span>
            <div>This is Product</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Using can use div to move the text to a new line as div acts as a block element